# Arrow function in Express exported class - Unexpected token

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, arrow-functions

I have file with my class which I exported and use in express and Node.
I'ld like to use arrow function and it's an example:

```
class MyClass {

    myFunc(arg) {
        console.log(arg);
    }

    myArrowFunc = (arg1, arg2) => {
        console.log(arg1);
        console.log(arg2);
    };
}


module.exports = {
    MyClass
}
```

Everything works fine before adding myArrowFunc. After that I have an error after run app:

```
myArrowFunc = (arg1, arg2) => {
            ^
SyntaxError: Unexpected token =
```

My Node version is 9.x so it should work... or I forgot about something.

Comment: What's the point of a method that's an arrow function anyway?  When you do that, it's not really a method of your object because `this` won't be the object instance.  What problem are you actually trying to solve?

Answer (score 4):

You can't put an assignment in a Class like that.

Why not put it in the **constructor**? You initialize properties in it.

No [babeljs](https://babeljs.io/) needed for that.

```js
class MyClass {
    constructor(){
        this.myArrowFunc = (arg1, arg2) => {
            console.log(arg1);
            console.log(arg2);
        };
    }
    myFunc(arg){
        console.log(arg);
    }
}
```

### Update

This is now possible ([Stage 3 proposal](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-class-fields) / [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes/Public_class_fields)):

```js
class MyClass {
    arrowFunc = (a, b) => {
        console.log(a, b);
    }
    myFunc(arg){
        console.log(arg);
    }
}
```

Comment: this is worked for me, but I don't get it why is not working without defining in constructor.

Answer (score 3):

Starting with node versions `v10.x.x`, you can use `node --harmony` to run code with arrow notation for class methods. Harmony flag enables new ECMAScript 6 features in the language.

Answer (score 0):

In order to use new Javascript (es6) in express app, you need to install babel to compile es6 to es5 code. The Babel compiler will allow you to use the new JavaScript features in Express app.

These dependencies are required to use the babel compiler in your project.

1) babel-cli: Compile files from the command line using babel

2) babel-preset-es2015: Babel preset for all es2015 plugins.

Run this command to install babel in your nodejs project using terminal

```
npm install -save-dev babel-cli babel-preset-es2015
```

Rest please follow this link https://www.codementor.io/iykyvic/writing-your-nodejs-apps-using-es6-6dh0edw2o

Comment: Pretty sure Node doesn't need babel for arrow functions to work nowadays. The issue is that the _experimental feature_ of class fields or property initializers (or whatever they're called) hasn't made it into Node, but they _are_ available through babel.

Comment: Trying to process the code in the question with Babel gives: `SyntaxError: module.js: Unexpected token (7:16)`

Comment: I'm not sure. Just in case if someone using the old version for eg: below 4.x.x ,hope it will help

Comment: Even in a recent version of Node this wouldn't work tho.